# How to launch an eclipse run configuration (for OSGI based project) from windows command line?

Tags: eclipse, command-line, osgi

I have an OSGI based project which run correctly from eclipse via a Run Configuration.
Actually I want to find a solution to launch it from the command line without launching eclipse.

Is there a solution to launch an eclipse run config from windows command line, or make a runnable file for this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the eclipse command line options here:

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html

This should give you enough to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the shell command Eclipse uses:

1. Run your program in Eclipse
2. Go to the "Debug" view
3. Right-click on the process (probably the second item in the tree) and select "Properties"